# In an international track competition, there are 5 US athletes, 4 russian, 3 french and 2 german. How many rankings of 14 athletes are there

Tags: combinatorics

In an internatiinal track competition,  there are  5 US athletes,  4 russian,  3 french and 2 german.  How many rankings of 14 athletes are there if only ntionality is counted and all US athletes must finish ahead of all Russian athletes?

Soln: This is similar to a question that has been asked before except that there was only 1 German instead of 2. I added in the extra athlete to try and see what would be done in such circumstances.  So the solution ti the problem of 1 german could be done through bars and stars.:

I let the 5 US and 4 Russians be 9 dividers and then have the 3 french as the stars,  which provides a solution of C(3 + 10 - 1, 9). Then to get the final solution I would multiply by the 13 possible spots for the German.

So say instead I had 2 Germans instead of the 1. I thought of two ways to handle this:

1. Treat all the french amd german athletes just as "athletes" and apply the 5 US and 4 Russians as dividers among that set. so the solution would instead be C(5 + 9 - 1, 5).
2. proceed as in the original question but instead of multiplying by 13 instead multiply as such:

$$\binom{13}{2} \binom{12}{3}$$

where $\binom{13}{2}$ is for all the ways that the 2 germans could fit into the arrangement.

Comment: Its just total ways-ways where russians are ahead

Comment: finding ways russians are ahead is just as complicated as finding ways US are ahead, I don't see the benefit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume ties are not possible. Use the letter F for French, G for German, and O for American or Russian. Then we want the number of $14$ letter words with exactly $3$ F, $2$ G, and $9$ O. For given any such word, the positions occupied by *all* nationalities are determined.

Comment: I don't see how the necessary ordering of the US and Russians is attained through O?

Comment: @dc3rd the first $5$ letters $O$ are for the US athletes.

Comment: just like that? ??? We're able to just casually designate within that set of O's which will be US and russian depending on their location in the arrangement???.........that doesn't sit well with me eventhough it is correct....

Comment: @dc3rd It is not very sportsmanlike, if that's what you mean.  I am sure the Russians won't take that :-). As answer to your question this is very nice, though.

Comment: @dc3rd: If, as is being considered, the Russians are barred from participating, your problem will greatly ease :-)

Answer (score 1):

The  ways are just given by r things out of which n,m..p are same is $\frac{r!}{n!.m!...p!}$ now can you get what i was saying.